# How to interpret `p_size` in ELF files?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, elf

Recently, I have been playing around ELF format files. And I tried to solve a problem:

> Given the `eip`, print the name of the function in the ELF executable file

And I can do this with symbol table and string table. Since I only need to deal with those symbols whose type is `STT_FUNC`, I wrote the following program:

```
for (i = 0; i < nr_symtab_entry; ++i) {
  if ((symtab[i].st_info == STT_FUNC) &&
      eip <  symtab[i].st_value + symtab[i].st_size &&
      eip >= symtab[i].st_value) {
        strcpy(funcName, strtab + symtab[i].st_name);
  }
}
```

where `symtab` is the symbol table, `strtab` is the string table.

But after several tests, I realized that the program above is wrong. After several trials, I changed it into this:

```
for (i = 0; i < nr_symtab_entry; ++i) {
  if ((symtab[i].st_info & STT_FUNC) &&
      eip <  symtab[i].st_value + symtab[i].st_size &&
      eip >= symtab[i].st_value) {
        strcpy(funcName, strtab + symtab[i].st_name);
  }
}
```

Then it worked! But when I `man elf`, the manual told me:

> **st_info**   This member specifies the symbol’s type and binding attributes

It didn't mention whether it is a bit flag or not. And then I encountered a problem which needs me to check whether a segment is `PT_LOAD`. And the manual, again, does not specify whether it is a bit flag or not. So I come here to ask for help---Is `PT_LOAD` also a bit flag? Is every symbol-constant like thing in ELF file a bit flag?

---

It seems that `st_info` can be interpreted by specific macros. But how about `p_type`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret the st\_info field of elf symbol table section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181509/how-to-interpret-the-st-info-field-of-elf-symbol-table-section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if (ELF32_ST_TYPE(symtab[i].st_info) == STT_FUNC && ...
```

like for example kernel does in [linux kernel/module.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/arch/arm/kernel/module.c#L191).

The ELF32_ST_TYPE is used to extract type of a symbol from the st_info. I can't find the list of which symbols are types of a symbol anywhere, but inspecting `#define ELF32_ST_TYPE(info)          ((info) & 0xf)` and definitions in [elf.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/uapi/linux/elf.h#L122) I can be pretty sure `ELF32_ST_TYPE(st_info)` is equal to one of the following macros:

```
#define STT_NOTYPE  0
#define STT_OBJECT  1
#define STT_FUNC    2
#define STT_SECTION 3
#define STT_FILE    4
#define STT_COMMON  5
#define STT_TLS     6
```

In `man elf` there it is:

> There are macros for packing and unpacking  the  binding  and
>                    type fields:
>
> ELF32_ST_BIND(info), ELF64_ST_BIND(info)
>           Extract a binding from an st_info value.
>
> ELF32_ST_TYPE(info), ELF64_ST_TYPE(info)
>           Extract a type from an st_info value.
>
> ELF32_ST_INFO(bind, type), ELF64_ST_INFO(bind, type)
>           Convert a binding and a type into an st_info value.

Comment: Yes. But how about `PT_LOAD`? Is there also a macro to unpack the type field of `p_type`? Or we just need to use `==`?

Comment: In this case just use `p_type == PT_LOAD`.